# How to make multiple document.getElementById() work on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am working on a little like function. The problem is there will be a few LIKE buttons on the same page. When I have just one everything is great, if more than one the top one works the rest do not. Unfortunately I can't change the `like` and `like2` ids. So, is there a way to make multiple `document.getElementById()` work on the same page? I tried changing them to `document.getElementsByClassName()[0];` and updating the script thinking that the class name may work, but it didn't. It does the same thing as `document.getElementById()`.

```
<script>
function myFunction<?php echo $favid;?>() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");
var text = document.getElementById("like");
if (checkBox.unchecked == true){
    text.style.display = "inline-block";
} else {
   text.style.display = "none";
}

    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");
var text = document.getElementById("like2");
if (checkBox.unchecked == true){
    text.style.display = "none";
} else {
   text.style.display = "inline-block";
}

var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");
var text = document.getElementById("like");
if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "none";
} else {
   text.style.display = "inline-block";
}

</script>
```

Comment: `id`, no matter what, needs to be unique per document.

Comment: how are these functions called? is it from a click?

Comment: What exactly does the markup look like for these _"LIKE buttons"_?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph yes, when a checkbox is checked / unchecked

Comment: @NidhinJoseph is it possible to make it work with ClassName instead??

Comment: mate, you need to give more info like share HTML or explain how these logic are invoked. There are ways to achieve this, but its better to explain something after you are clear with what you want.

Comment: @Phil it's a long one. Not sure if I should post it. Should I?

Comment: Again, **you cannot have more than one element with any given `id` value**. That is **invalid** HTML and **you *must* fix that**. There is no other option.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone. I finally figured it out. All I needed to do was to add `<?php echo $favid;?>` to the ids in the HTML and the javascript code (which made them unique since `$favid` is unique for all posts):

```
<script>
function myFunction<?php echo $favid;?>() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");
var text = document.getElementById("like <?php echo $favid;?>");
if (checkBox.unchecked == true){
text.style.display = "inline-block";
} else {
text.style.display = "none";
}

var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");
var text = document.getElementById("like2 <?php echo $favid;?>");
if (checkBox.unchecked == true){
text.style.display = "none";
} else {
text.style.display = "inline-block";
}

var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");
var text = document.getElementById("like <?php echo $favid;?>");
if (checkBox.checked == true){
text.style.display = "none";
} else {
text.style.display = "inline-block";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `document.querySelectorAll("#myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");`

With `document.querySelector(selector)` you can locate/get all element that is having the selector you put in. The format of the selector is the same as the one you use when styling a element using CSS.

`document.querySelectorAll(selector)` selects all elements with the matching attribute/selector.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("#myCheck<?php echo $favid;?>");

checkBoxes.forEach(function (checkBox) {
    if (checkBox.checked) {
        text.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        text.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Not sure, maybe I am not doing it right, but the code doesn't work. Even the top like button doesn't work with it (which it does with the old code).

Comment: Ok thanks. I've fixed it. It was supposed to be `checkBoxes.forEach(...)` instead of `checkBox.forEach(...)`